AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'. Did you mean: '__ne__'?
app = Flask(__name__)

def make_bold(function):
    def wrapper():
        
        return '<b>' + function() + '</b>'
    return wrapper()



@app.route("/")
@make_bold

def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


app.run(debug=True)

Why is this error keeps coming. How do i fix it?

return wrapper without the parenthesis; don't call the function at that point.

 def make_bold(function):
    def wrapper():
        return '<b>' + function() + '</b>'
    return wrapper  <------ # Remove the parentheses here

  # Run the Flask application
  if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)

